# On-Topicness of programming questions in general

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Strongly related [discussion](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178/on-topicness-of-embedded-programming-questions). We should widen this site-scope discussion to handle all possibly emerging programming questions not just the embedded aspect.

We certainly will have questions about the followng APIs for example:

- [libmosquito API](https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html)
- [HiveMQ developer guide](http://www.hivemq.com/docs/plugins/latest/)
- [RabbitMQ management HTTP API](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_3_4/priv/www/api/index.html)

I consider these on-topic at the moment, but then we should allow questions about any other web-service API too.

Maybe some questions about scripting will show up as well so all in all we should cover/handle all programming question from the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no problem with that as long as there is a certain connectivity/IoT aspect to the use case. There might even be some APIs like the ones you list that should be generally on-topic.

The really generic programming stuff without IoT connection, embeddedness or the like belongs on Stack Overflow.